# Exception loading CustomMeta from Tridion Broker Service (2009 SP1)

Tags: tridion

I am trying to load some Custom Meta from a component which is published into the Tridion Broker.

This is 2009 SP1

I can see the component in the Custom_Meta table with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Tridion_Broker].[dbo].[CUSTOM_META] WHERE ITEM_ID = 204221
```

However using the below code, I get a Java Runtime exception on the line where I do GetMeta. I have noticed that if my queryStringId is a proper TCM ID then it will throw the excpetion but if I just put the item Id it will return null.

```
string queryStringId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["component_uri"]);

string pageId = ((BasePage) Page).PageTcmId;
int publicationId = int.Parse(pageId.Split(':')[1].Split('-')[0]);
using (var cmf = new ComponentMetaFactory(publicationId))
{
    IComponentMeta cm = cmf.GetMeta(queryStringId);
    if(cm != null)
    {
        VideoId = cm.CustomMeta.GetValue("video_url").ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        litMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[RuntimeException]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +351
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1278
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +551
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, Type declaredType, Boolean bLeaf, JavaMethodArguments jargs) +50
   Com.Tridion.Meta.ComponentMetaFactory.GetMeta(Int32 componentId) +118
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.ComponentMetaFactory.GetMeta(Int32 componentId) +16
   ASP._controls_video_ascx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs args) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\borland\us\_controls\Video.ascx:18
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

**Update**
I have looked in the Broker log with the log enabled on "info" level and am seeing nothing after "Tridion Broker is enabled". Is this a configuration or DLL problem? It looks like the CD is not calling the service at all?

**Update 2**
I have tried a lot of things and still no help. It's like the code is not able to communicate with the JVM, however I can see the JVM being started in the event log.

Comment: This is typically caused by not having the right JVM on your machine. Make sure you have both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs installed (I don't remember why, but am quite sure somebody will tell us that in a few minutes).

Comment: Have you installed 32 or 64 bit java? And are you using the matching Tridion Content Delivery DLLs?

Comment: 32bit server with 32 bit java. I am using x86 DLLs from within the installer.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Java 1.6? I think you may be using the JDBC driver is for Java 1.5, if so download the latest driver from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21599)

Also double check all your bindings in broker config!

Comment: Not sure which of these it was but I have copied the bindings from another project and updated the JDBC driver JAR file and everything now works.

Comment: JDBC driver is not shipped with Tridion

Comment: That's a good point actually Nuno. I think the one we had in our install folder was the wrong one or perhaps my bindings were the problem after all - updated Chris' answer to reflect this.

Comment: Missing JARs (ClassNotFoundError exceptions) should be caught in the logs. Did you see any?

Answer (score 4):

Typically when I had this kind of error, it was because one of the following:

- the Java run-time was not installed or available to the web-app (from previous comments I see this is not the case for you). Have you checked the event viewer (either Tridion or Tridion Content Manager) for errors? Something like 'Unable to locate JVM'...
- missing JAR - a Tridion or 3rd party JAR is missing from your classpath (which could be under your `webroot/bin/lib`);
- configuration error (Tridion config is wrong, somewhere in `webroot/bin/config`);
- missing license file (check the `webroot/bin/config/cd_licenses.xml` or maybe your config files point to another `cd_licenses.xml`, which might not be available or accessible to the web app app-pool user). A missing license is maybe the trickiest. All you see in the log is a subtle mention stating that due to missing/expired license, the Broker has reverted to 'file system'. This means no communication with the CD DB will be made -- for Custom meta this is a no go;

The last 3 errors will be somewhat present in a log file. So make sure you have the log level debug enabled and look for any stack traces in the cd_core and cd_broker logs.

Last but not least, make sure your website app-pool is unique to the Tridion website (do not reuse in other website). Check the .net version used (recommend 4.0) and check the user running it (recommend Network Service).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I configure the cd_core log?

Comment: In a file called logback.xml that typically is in your bin/config folder.

Comment: cd_core.log is only for Tridion 2011 - you don't have this in 2009, check the individual cd_*_conf.xml files for log locations and log levels.

Comment: Very good point. I was under the impression that you were upgrading from 2009 to 2011...