# Date/DateTime object type in AmbientDataFramework

Tags: tridion

I'm having a bit of an issue with the Date (java) / DateTime (.net) type when using the Ambient Data Framework in SDL Tridion 2009.

I'm setting a claim value in java like this:

```
Date myDate = rs.getDate("DATE_FIELD_IN_DB");
store.put(CLAIM_URI_DATE, myDate);
```

This is great and life is fantastic :)

In my web application (which is .net)  I need to get this value from the claim store, when I try to do so, it fails:

My code is:

```
if (_store.Contains(new Uri("taf:claim:company:date"))) {
  DateTime claimdata = _store.Get<DateTime>("taf:claim:company:date"); 
  Response.Write(claimdata.ToString());
}
```

And the error message is:

> [RuntimeException]    Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
>   +373    Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1365    Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallInt(JavaProxy jpo) +233    Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.JuggerNetTypeHelper.FromProxyObject(Object
>   proxyObject) +738
>   Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore.Get(Uri claimUri) +109

I've also tried obtaining as an object, which i then cast to DateTime.   I'm obviously making a really basic error here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also read the SDL documentation here : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_26FDE76C277D43F893175E512EFDF09A which shows the java Data object is converted to the .net DateTime.

Thanks

John

**UPDATE**

As per the suggestions of Peter, i've check and ensured the correct jar files are in place.

It might be worth mentioning that the date is stored in a SQL database as a 'Date' type, a typical value doesn't include a timestamp, for example '2011-09-03'.  Still this all functions great in Java and I can work with the value as a date.   Still when getting the value in .Net the typed exception is thrown.

Comment: Hello John, did my suggestion help you in any way?

Answer (score 6):

It should convert it automatically. Are you sure you are not using a different Date object than java.util.Date, though? There's quite a few of them out there...

If you really cannot get it to work, you can work around it by storing the date as a string (in ISO 8601 format) and then using DateTime.Parse on the .NET side.

But like I said: it normally works fine so there's probably something else going wrong.

Is your ADF working fine for other things in .NET? Maybe it's missing a setup step for the .NET side of things...

Comment: Hi Peter,  I'm afraid I can't convert to string as the value is used in Smart Target as a Trigger type.

I've forced the variable to be java.util.Date and in the logs when it's output the date is written... it is a really weird one.  Will update here once i've got to the bottom of it

Answer (score 4):

A bit of a long shot, but can you verify that the right JDBC driver is installed as mentioned in this question/answer?

[Exception loading CustomMeta from Tridion Broker Service (2009 SP1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122587/exception-loading-custommeta-from-tridion-broker-service-2009-sp1)

The Date value, does it contain the time? Can you ensure that it does when you get the value from the store?